# Why is DataInputStream.readFully(...) hanging?

Tags: java, http, stream

I'm having a difficult time understanding what is going wrong in my application. Below shows code that successfully executes on first pass (a prior `HttpResponse`, and then on its second call, hangs at the `dataInputStream.readFully(...)` line.

```
doSomething(HttpResponse response) {
    HttpEntity responseBody = response.getEntity();
    long len = responseBody.getContentLength();
    byte[] payload = new byte[(int)len]; // <-- I've confirmed this is the correct length

    DataInputStream d = null;
    try {
        InputStream bais = responseBody.getContent();
        d = new DataInputStream(bais); 
        d.readFully(payload); // <-- *** HANGS HERE! ***

        EntityUtils.consume(responseBody);
        ...
    } finally {
        if (d != null) {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(d);
        }
    }
}
```

After blocking/hanging for 10+ seconds, the application times out and the calling thread is torn down.

- I've inspected the `response` object, and confirmed its Content-Length to be what is expected.
- Nothing jumped out at me reading the `DataInputStream` [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html).
- Going through our commit history, I noticed that the `IOUtils.closeQuietly(...)` call was introduced. [Trust me here:] It's been hard to track our integration system's initial failure of this application, so I cannot confirm whether this `finally` block introduced any unintended behavior. From what I can tell, calling `closeQuietly()` there is the recommended approach.

**Update:** For clarity, this code is part of an application performing HTTP RANGED GET requests. E.g., first `response` is pulling down *N* bytes, starting at byte 0. The second call GETs the next *N* bytes. The file is large, so there are more than two necessary RANGED GETs.

Comment: Maybe also close the `InputStream bais`?

Comment: To confirm: `response` is different the second time round? OTOH the basic http entity was non-repeatable.

Comment: @dhke Yes, I'm updating to confirm what's going on... standby.

Comment: It doesn't hang at the constructor. It hangs trying to fill the buffer in `readFully()`.

Comment: @MarkKeen I don't see why. He knows the size of this input stream.

Comment: @EJP you're right re: the `readFully()` call vs. constructor. That was just a mistake when typing up the sample code.

Comment: If someone is going to downvote, I'd love to know why.

Comment: Clearly the server isn't delivering all the data within your timeout period, or possibly not at all. Are you confident that its Content-lengths are correct?

Comment: @EJP Agreed. I'm not convinced the content-length is correctly representing the body. I'd prematurely assumed that since it matched my  _anticipated_ value that the body was therefore the correct length. So it seems like I'm giving the (custom-code) server more respect than I should.

Comment: @EJP it turned out to be something in the underlying infrastructure -- via wireshark, we were seeing TCP packet loss, so the HTTP body wasn't arriving in its entirety.